# splinter - strange ElementNotVisible exception for link that is indeed visible in dumped html/screenshot

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, splinter

I am running some browser tests with splinter and, at one point, come across a page with a link I want to follow. This call succeeds and returns the link:

```
my_browser.find_link_by_partial_href('/mystuff/' + str(important_number))
```

But I cannot click it:

```
my_browser.find_link_by_partial_href('/mystuff/' + str(important_number)).click()
...
...
...
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'{"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"81","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:38495","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\\"sessionId\\": \\"7812e810-9100-11e4-881c-37067349397d\\", \\"id\\": \\":wdc:1420039695427\\"}","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/7812e810-9100-11e4-881c-37067349397d/element/%3Awdc%3A1420039695427/click"}}' ; Screenshot: available via screen
```

What's odd here is that the link is indeed present when I follow `my_browser.url`, as well as if I look at `my_browser.html` or try`browser.show_screenshot(my_browser)`.

And it doesn't seem to be an issue of waiting for visibility. Adding a quick `import time(); time.wait(5);` before the click still doesn't work (nor do longer waits, though that's probably more than sufficient).

What could I be missing here?

Comment: Have you tried with different selector like `xpath` and it's probably looking for another link which is hidden

Comment: Oh...yes. I answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. Splinter is defaulting to the first link it finds, which isn't visible:

```
(Pdb) [link.visible for link in my_browser.find_link_by_partial_href('/mystuff/' + str(important_number))]

[False, True]
```

This extra hidden link isn't supposed to be there in the first place, which goes to show you what can happen if you make assumptions about your code - even the seemingly irrelevant parts!

Comment: That's what I suspected